# Telepot lock reply_keyboard python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telepot

I have a problem.
I created a telegram bot under python3 with telepot and I use a custom keyboard.

the problem is that when i press a button, the custom keyboard is hidden by the phone keypad.

is it possible to temporarily lock the custom keyboard open or block the phone keyboard?

I already tested one_time_keyboard and it didn't work.

```
markupmainmenuadmin = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[["menu 1"],["info 1"],["info 2"],["info 3"],["Admin"]],resize_keyboard = True,one_time_keyboard = True)
[...]
bot.sendMessage(chat_id,str(textdb.get(query.nom == 'MainMenu2').get("text")),disable_web_page_preview=True, reply_markup=markupmainmenuadmin, parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```

it only happens when you stay on the same keyboard.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KCWuyni
the video of the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
markupmainmenuadmin =InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[InlineKeyboardButton(text="menu 1", callback_data='0')],[InlineKeyboardButton(text="info 1", callback_data='1')],[InlineKeyboardButton(text="info 2", callback_data='2')],[InlineKeyboardButton(text="info 3", callback_data='3')],[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Admin", callback_data='4')]])
```

Comment: Needs more editing, there is no question. I think you have added the question as answer....? So please edit question so other can help to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but will there be a way to do this with ReplyKeyboardMarkup ?

Comment: No.There is no way